# Regex - match up to first literal

Tags: regex

I have some lines of code I am trying to remove some leading text from which appears like so:

```
Line 1: myApp.name;
Line 2: myApp.version
Line 3: myApp.defaults, myApp.numbers;
```

I am trying and trying to find a regex that will remove anything up to (but excluding) `myApp`.

I have tried various regular expressions, but they all seem to fail when it comes to line 3 (because myApp appears twice).

The closest I have come so far is:

```
.*?myApp
```

Pretty simple - but that matches both instances of myApp occurrences in Line 3 - whereas I'd like it to match only the first.

There's a few hundred lines - otherwise I'd have deleted them all manually by now.

Can somebody help me? Thanks.

Comment: Where is this running?   Does it have search and replace capability?

Comment: `^.*?myApp` will do the trick. Next time, please, specify the platform/language you need the regex for - they DO have differences.

Comment: I'll be using it in Notepad++ to do a large replace.

Comment: Thanks guys! Will do, it escaped me this time but I certainly will do next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an anchor `^` which matches the starting point of a line ,

```
^.*?(myApp)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oY5nA8/3)

Use the above regex and replace the matched characters with `$1` or `\1`. So that you could get the string `myApp` in the final result after replacement.

**Pattern explanation:**

- `^` Start of a line.
- `.*?(myApp)` Shortest possible match upto the first `myApp`. The string `myApp` was captured and stored into a group.(*group 1*)
- All matched characters are replaced with the chars present inside the group 1.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why the carat makes all the difference? I need to brush up on my regex skills.

Comment: I understand it signifies the beginning of a line, but cannot understand how it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression works in Perl if you add the `^` to ensure that you only match the beginnings of lines:

```
cat /tmp/test.txt  | perl -pe 's/^.*?myApp/myApp/g'
myApp.name;
myApp.version
myApp.defaults, myApp.numbers;
```

If you wanted to get fancy, you could put the "myApp" into a group that doesn't get captured as part of the expression using `(?=)` syntax.  That way it doesn't have to be replaced back in.

```
cat /tmp/test.txt  | perl -pe 's/^.*?(?=myApp)//g'
myApp.name;
myApp.version
myApp.defaults, myApp.numbers;
```

Comment: Thanks - why does the carat make all the difference? That was all that was missing from mine and I am struggling to see how it helps.

Comment: It means to match from the beginning of the string.  Without it, there are two matches in the third line:  `Line 3: myApp` and `.defaults, myApp`, both of which get removed.  Only one of them starts the line, so the caret helps.